# Setup Windows Media Player 11 to stream from TVersity

Tags: streaming, windows-server-2003, windows-media-player

I've got TVersity installed on a Windows 2003 server box (work had an extra license that they donated to let me install at home to get some practice setting up/administering a domain etc.)

I found out that Windows Media Player 11 won't install on Windows 2003, but installed TVersity instead and streaming to my 360 is working great. Problem is that I don't know how to setup streaming to any other PC on the network. All of the PCs have access to the shared network folder, but playing from there doesn't stream and the stutter is pretty bad.

Is there a way to setup Windows Media Player 11 or another player to stream from TVersity?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in Windows Media Player's Options (right-click somewhere on the window chrome near the top, select Tools -> Options), select the Library tab and then click on Configure Sharing. There should be a "Find media that others are sharing" tick box. You probably want to check that's ticked.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using Windows Media Player 10 or higher out of the box this should automatically come up as a shared library. There is normally no configuration required. I would look at potentially a firewall blocking access. I successfully ran TVersity like this for more then a year.

You may need to check under Media Player settings that looking for shared media is enabled. I have Windows 7 and the streaming options have changed, but remember this was an option in other versions.

Alternatively you can try [XBMC](http://www.xbmc.org) to play video's, since it has better support for the folder structures.

Also ensure you are not using multiple network cards to connect to your network on the host machine. TVersity only binds to a single IP address, and if it is not visible to the network your PC's are on it won't allow streaming. I had to switch to [Twonky Media Server](http://www.twonkyvision.de) because of this limitation.

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to get it working under wmp, but I did set media center to do it without any problems. I can live with it as is.